# Make dependency between inputs in UI

Tags: r, shiny

There are 2 dateinputs: `date1` and `date2`. The `date2` should not be before `date1`. How to make the dependency in UI?

What should I write in `min =` of `date2`?
I have tried: `min = input$date1`, `min = 'input$date1'`, `min = 'input.date1'`, `'min = 'input.date1''`, `"min = 'input$date1'"`, `"min = 'input.date1'"` but it doesn't work.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
   dateInput("date1", "date 1"),
   dateInput("date2", "date 2 = not be before date 1", min = 'input.date1') 
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

Also can use `observeEvent`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dateInput("date1", "date 1"),
  dateInput("date2", "date 2 = not be before date 1") 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$date1,{
    updateDateInput(session, "date2", min = input$date1 + 1,value = input$date1 + 1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you can achieve this purely in the `UI`, but you can use  `updateDateInput` in the server logic to get the required behaviour:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dateInput("date1", "date 1"),
  dateInput("date2", "date 2 = not be before date 1") 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    req(input$date1)
    ## whenever input$date1 changes, change min of input$date2
    updateDateInput(session, "date2", min = input$date1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```